# gnuplot heatmap z-value data does not match color bar range

Tags: gnuplot

I'm creating a heatmap from a file with columns x, y, z. I get a heatmap with what seems to be corrsct positions of peaks in the data, however, the peak values are about 1/10th the z-values in my data.

I have tried using set cbrange to change the colo bar range, but this only leads to plot in which the peaks get washed out.

Here are my data format, code, and output image respectively:

Data format (data has 200 X 200 elements):

```
   1.665      -0.031       0.355
   1.634      -0.031       0.395
   1.602      -0.031       0.434
   1.571      -0.031       0.471
   1.539      -0.031       0.505
   1.508      -0.031       0.533
   1.477      -0.031       0.555
   1.445      -0.031       0.568
   1.414      -0.031       0.571
   1.382      -0.031       0.563
   1.351      -0.031       0.546
```

Code:

```
set view map
set dgrid3 200,200,1
set xrange [-3.14:3.14]
set yrange [-3.14:3.14]
set termoption enhanced
set xlabel '{/Symbol f}_{i + 1}'
set ylabel '{/Symbol y}_{i}' off -3,0
set size square
set palette defined (0 0 0 0.5, 1 0 0 1, 2 0 0.5 1, 3 0 1 1, 4 0.5 1 0.5, 5 1 1 0, 6 1 0.5 0, 7 1 0 0, 8 0.5 0 0)
splot "plot-pmf-out4.dat" using 1:2:3 with pm3d
set terminal postscript eps enhanced
set output "pmf-plot4.eps"
replot
```

[resulting image after calling gnuplot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sq8AC.png)

Comment: Without seeing the full data set I can only guess, and my guess is that the `norm 1` transform in dgrid3d is flattening your data values.  If the data is already a 200x200 grid, why are you calling dgrid3d at all?

Comment: The full data set is exactly like the sample above (there are no blank lines, and the min / max z-values are 0.0 and ~0.6). I tried removing dgrid3d from the code, but when I run it gnuplot doesn't create a plot and gives a warning message about a single isoline not being enough for a pm3d plot. I'm a complete novice at gnuplot. The code just consists of fragments I cobbled together from help pages and trial and error.

Comment: The z values are not the issue.  The point was that you don't show enough of the data to determine if the ordering of x/y coordinates matches what gnuplot expects for a regular grid.  If it does, then removing the `set dgrid3d` may fix everything.  If you do need the extra gridding step, then the issue becomes what is the appropriate weighting function to generate the grid. You have used "qnorm 1.0".  Try "set dgrid3d 200,200 spline" or maybe "set dgrid3d 200,200 gauss kdensity pi/200, pi/200".

Comment: I see. I doubt that my data is ordered correctly. Let me look into what gnuplot expects for a regular grid.